# Automaper. Map property from json

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, automapper

I have a model for response. In the model I need to load queries from JSON file. For example I load json data from the const. In the entity (`Problem`) property `Queries` is not needed, so absent.

This is model:

```
public class ProblemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsResolved { get; set; }
    public ICollection<QueryModel> Queries{ get; set; }
    public int State {get; set; }
}
```

And this is `QueryModel`:

```
public class QueryModel
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public QueryModel[] Accept { get; set; }
    public QueryModel[] No { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Automapper profile

```
public class ProblemMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ProblemMappingProfile()
    {
        const string jsonData = @"[
          {
             'Query': 'Query1',
             'Accept': [
                {
                    'Query': 'Query1_1',
                    'Accept': [
                       { }
                    ],
                    'Reject': [
                        { }
             ]
           }
        ],
        'Reject': [
            {
                'Query': 'Query1_2',
                'Accept': [
                    { }
                ],
                'Reject': [
                    { }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    ]";
            QueryModel[] json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<QueryModel[]>(jsonData.Replace('\'', '\"'));

        CreateMap<Problem, ProblemModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Queries, o => o.MapFrom(s => json))
                .ReverseMap()
    }
}
```

I need to load queries every time when `ProblemModel` mapped. For example:

```
return _mapper.Map<ProblemModel>(await _context.Problems.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync());
```

or

```
return _mapper.Map<ProblemModel>(await _context.Problems.Where(x => x.state == 2).ToListAsync());
```

I've tried to map in `Queries` in automapper profile but it's wrong. Because profile constructor works once. After constructing automapping profile I get an error

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.ArgumentException: Field 'SimplyQuery.Services.Models.ProblemMappingProfile+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.json' is not defined for type 'SimplyQuery.Data.Entities.Problem'

So I can't understand:

1. Where I need to map json data for dynamically include it into result model(s)? And how I can do this?
2. Why do I get an error in constructor? The JSON data was deserialized well, so array must be assigned to another array, no?

Comment: you should create a class (dto) for your json data and map that DTO class to actual entities.

Comment: QuerryModel is the DTO class. For entity from db I don't need this querries. It is additional data in DTO when creating response.

Comment: Looks like you can do much quicker by doing it manually in the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if my post was not clear for understanding. I've solved my problem. I changed my automapper profile:

```
public class ProblemMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        private string jsonData = @"[
            {
                'Query': 'Query1',
                'Accept': [
                    {
                        'Query': 'Query1_1',
                        'Accept': [
                            { }
                        ],
                        'Reject': [
                            { }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                'Reject': [
                    {
                        'Query': 'Query1_2',
                        'Accept': [
                            { }
                        ],
                        'Reject': [
                            { }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]";
        
        private QueryModel[] queries;
        
        public ProblemMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Problem, ProblemModel>()
                .BeforeMap((src, dest) => GetQuestions(@"Models\LandParcelModels\StateLandCadQuestions.json"))
                .ForMember(d => d.Queries, o => o.MapFrom(s => queries.ToList()))
                .ReverseMap()
        }
        
        private void GetQuestions(string questionsFilePath)
        {
            // here will be loading data into jsonData from file 
            queries = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<QueryModel[]>(jsonData.Replace('\'', '\"'));
        }
        
    }
```